# Fast inserting to array/sql

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I got this code

```
$i             = -1;
$random_string = array();
while (sizeof($random_string) < 1600000) {
    $i++;
    $zmienna           = generatePassword();
    if (!in_array($zmienna, $random_string))
        $random_string[$i] = $zmienna;
    else
        continue;
}
//print_r($random_string);

foreach ($random_string as $value) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `kody`(`kod`) VALUES ('$value')";
    mysql_query($sql, $con);
}
```

But it will take a lot of hours to insert it to databse, or even to array. Do someone know how to improve this code?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but.. don't use the `mysql_` functions! They are deprecated, unmaintained and will be removed in a future version of PHP.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: Rocket and Adrian's answers are both correct.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `in_array()` is rather expensive.  Use a hash instead of a simple array, and then you can use `isset()` instead of `in_array()`.

Also, don't use things like `sizeof()` and `count()` as loop conditions.  Instead, just use a simple `for ($i = 0; $i < 1600000; ++$i) { ... }` array.

Depending on your web host permissions, another significant optimization would be to use [`fputcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to write your array to disk and then make use of MySQL's [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to load the contents into your database, instead of generating 1.6 million queries.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you may not have permission to use `LOAD DATA INFILE`.  Depends on your web host.

Comment: @Rocket: Thanks, that's a very good point.  I'll add a note about it.

Comment: could you tell me how use hash?Becouse I didn't use it ever

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use one query to insert all of them at once with an SQL multi-insert:

```
$values = "('" . implode( "'), ('", $random_string) . "')";
$sql="INSERT INTO `kody`(`kod`) VALUES " . $values;
mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

As drrcknlsn very correctly points out, `in_array()` is inefficient, as it performs a linear O(n) search on the array. Here is how you can fix that (which is a hash implementation):

```
while( sizeof($random_string) < 1600000) {
    $i++;
    $zmienna = generatePassword();
    if( !isset( $random_string[$zmienna]))
        $random_string[$zmienna] = $zmienna;
    else
        continue;
}
```

Now, you can use the above code to generate a single SQL query, and this should run much, much faster.

Comment: Careful with this - if the size of the query string exceeds max_allowed_packet, things are going to go boom. Doing multi-value inserts is definitely more efficient, but you have to worry about going too far.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that it's trying to update the INDEX after each insert.  Try using transactions.  This will only update the INDEX once (after `COMMIT`) is called.  This will also let you `ROLLBACK` if something goes wrong.

```
mysql_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");

foreach($random_string as $value)
{
$sql="INSERT INTO `kody`(`kod`) VALUES ('$value')";
   mysql_query($sql,$con);
}

mysql_query("COMMIT");
```